# Sql Server - Join on Aggregate IN clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm trying to find a count of transactions where 2 categories are present.

I have 3 categories: chair, table, cup

Which becomes 9 combinations (ignoring dupes and order) using a CROSS JOIN:

```
Item_1  Item_2
Table   Table
Table   Chair
Table   Cup
Chair   Chair
Chair   Table
Chair   Cup
Cup     Cup
Cup     Chair
Cup     Table
```

Next there's a table of transaction id's and category at the line level:

```
Trans_id    Type
123         Table
123         Cup
234         Chair
345         Cup
345         Table
```

I'm trying to get a table like this showing the 2 categories and the count of distinct transactions with both categories present:

```
Item_1  Item_2  Count
Table   Table   578
Table   Chair   826
Table   Cup     370
Chair   Chair   235
Chair   Table   736
Chair   Cup     662
Cup     Cup     306
Cup     Chair   262
Cup     Table   839
```

I thought I'd be able to do something like:

```
select item1, item2, count(distinct(trans_id))
from t1
join t2
   on t1.item1 IN (SELECT type FROM t2 group by trans_id)
   and t1.item2 IN (SELECT type FROM t2 group by trans_id)
```

but not having any luck - any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join the transactions table twice once for item1 and once for item2. A `group by` thereafter will get you the counts.

```
select t2.item1, t2.item2, count(distinct t11.trans_id) 
from t2
join t1 t11 on t2.item1 = t11.type 
join t1 t12 on t2.item2 = t12.type 
where t11.trans_id=t12.trans_id
group by t2.item1, t2.item2
```

`t1` in this query is the transaction table, `t2` is the one which has combinations of items.

This query produces symmetric pairs like (table,chair), (chair,table) and each combination will be counted twice for each transaction id. I am not sure if you need that. More clarification needed here.